# italicising et al in apa citation format using apacite, latex

Tags: citing, apa-style, apacite

I'm currently working on my master's thesis. It's a requirement that all in-text citations with multiple authors, other authors should be represented by **et al** which should be in italics. I have generated a database of references using Jabref. For citation purposes, I am using the `apacite` package. Below is a sample `.tex` text.

`Broadly, there are two frameworks for analyzing repeated measures data: the Single Measures Framework (SMF) and the Repeated Measures Framework (RMF) \cite{Rose2015}.`

I expect the following

Broadly, there are two frameworks for analyzing repeated measures data, that is,
Single Measures Framework (SMF) and Repeated Measures Framework (RMF) (Rose *et al*., 2015).

But I get

Broadly, there are two frameworks for analyzing repeated measures data, that is,
Single Measures Framework (SMF) and Repeated Measures Framework (RMF) (Rose et al., 2015).

Below is a sample BibTeX entry:

```
@Article{Rose2015,
  author    = {Rose, Charles E and Gardner, Lytt and Craw, Jason and Girde, Sonali and Wawrzyniak, Andrew J and Drainoni, Mari-Lynn and Davila, Jessica and DeHovitz, Jack and Keruly, Jeanne C and Westfall, and others},
  journal   = {PloS one},
  title     = {{A comparison of methods for analyzing viral load data in studies of HIV patients}},
  year      = {2015},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {e0130090},
  volume    = {10},
  publisher = {Public Library of Science San Francisco, CA USA},
}
```

**Any help on how I can go over this will be higly appreciated**

Comment: As a follow up on the above, below if the bibtext file 

@Article{Rose2015,
  author    = {Rose, Charles E and Gardner, Lytt and Craw, Jason and Girde, Sonali and Wawrzyniak, Andrew J and Drainoni, Mari-Lynn and Davila, Jessica and DeHovitz, Jack and Keruly, Jeanne C and Westfall, and others},
  journal   = {PloS one},
  title     = {{A comparison of methods for analyzing viral load data in studies of HIV patients}},
  year      = {2015},
  number    = {6},
  pages     = {e0130090},
  volume    = {10},
  publisher = {Public Library of Science San Francisco, CA USA},
}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Instead of putting this in a comment, edit your question. It would also help to show a minimal document that could use this example for people to play with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the others string is determined by the `\BOthers` macro. It needs to be redefined at the beginning of the document rather than in the preamble, so we wrap the new definition in `\AtBeginDocument`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @Article{Rose2015, author = {Rose, Charles E and Gardner, Lytt and Craw, Jason and Girde, Sonali and Wawrzyniak, Andrew J and Drainoni, Mari-Lynn and Davila, Jessica and DeHovitz, Jack and Keruly, Jeanne C and Westfall, and others}, journal = {PloS one}, title = {{A comparison of methods for analyzing viral load data in studies of HIV patients}}, year = {2015}, number = {6}, pages = {e0130090}, volume = {10}, publisher = {Public Library of Science San Francisco, CA USA}, }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BOthers}{\emph{et al}\hbox{}}
}
\begin{document}

\cite{Rose2015}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you Alan, the issue has been resolved,

Because I had a long list of references, I simply replaced the bib file here with the data base names as below, It has worked 

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
% Encoding: UTF-8
problems 
Problem
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BOthers}{\emph{et al}\hbox{}}
} 


I then put this at the end of the document

\bibliography{problems, Problem}

Thank you once again

Comment: @SendegeSusanHabert Yes of course. I just included the `.bib` file in the document to make the example self-contained for the site.